# Nested controllers class definitions under parent directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quick question, I’m building a rails app that has the ability to contain multiple “features” one of those being rsyslog, other features could be any other software. Below is the current construct:

**Controllers:**

```
features/
features/rsyslog/
features/rsyslog/rsyslog_inputs_controller.rb
features/rsyslog/rsyslog_outputs_controller.rb
features/rsyslog/rsyslog_rules_controller.rb
```

**Routes:**

```
resources :features do
  scope module: "features/rsyslog” do
    resources :rsyslog_inputs
    resources :rsyslog_outputs
    resources :rsyslog_rules
  end
end
```

*(controller code does not work here)*

**Controller code:**

```
class Features::RsyslogInputsController < ApplicationController;end
class Features::RsyslogOutputsController < ApplicationController;end
class Features::RsyslogRulesController < ApplicationController;end
```

I’m curious, given that there are multiple features and I’d like to keep each features controllers nested in a directory specific to that feature.. i.e. (rsyslog containing all of the rsyslog controllers) as opposed to building the structure like so:

```
features/
features/rsyslog_inputs_controller.rb
features/rsyslog_outputs_controller.rb
features/rsyslog_rules_controller.rb
```

How does that translate to the controller code class definition? doing this:

```
Class Features::Rsyslog::RsyslogInputsController < ApplicationController; end
```

*(note the addition of Rsyslog above)*

RubyMine it’s getting pissy with a “expected end of line” on the second set of “::” in the class definition... However, the routes work.. Am I missing something here? is this just my IDE being weird?

Comment: Sorry, the very last code example, "class" is actually not capitalized, missed that in my question creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app/features/rsyslog/inputs_controller.rb
```

Should define

```
class Features::Rsyslog::InputsController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Not

```
class Features::Rsyslog::RsyslogInputsController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Then:

```
scope :features do
  scope :rsyslog do
    resources :inputs,  controller: 'features/rsyslog/inputs'
    resources :outputs, controller: 'features/rsyslog/outputs'
    resources :rules,   controller: 'features/rsyslog/rules'
  end
end
```

Which yields:

```
      inputs GET    /features/rsyslog/inputs(.:format)              features/rsyslog/inputs#index
             POST   /features/rsyslog/inputs(.:format)              features/rsyslog/inputs#create
   new_input GET    /features/rsyslog/inputs/new(.:format)          features/rsyslog/inputs#new
  edit_input GET    /features/rsyslog/inputs/:id/edit(.:format)     features/rsyslog/inputs#edit
       input GET    /features/rsyslog/inputs/:id(.:format)          features/rsyslog/inputs#show
             PATCH  /features/rsyslog/inputs/:id(.:format)          features/rsyslog/inputs#update
             PUT    /features/rsyslog/inputs/:id(.:format)          features/rsyslog/inputs#update
             DELETE /features/rsyslog/inputs/:id(.:format)          features/rsyslog/inputs#destroy
     outputs GET    /features/rsyslog/outputs(.:format)             features/rsyslog/outputs#index
             POST   /features/rsyslog/outputs(.:format)             features/rsyslog/outputs#create
  new_output GET    /features/rsyslog/outputs/new(.:format)         features/rsyslog/outputs#new
 edit_output GET    /features/rsyslog/outputs/:id/edit(.:format)    features/rsyslog/outputs#edit
      output GET    /features/rsyslog/outputs/:id(.:format)         features/rsyslog/outputs#show
             PATCH  /features/rsyslog/outputs/:id(.:format)         features/rsyslog/outputs#update
             PUT    /features/rsyslog/outputs/:id(.:format)         features/rsyslog/outputs#update
             DELETE /features/rsyslog/outputs/:id(.:format)         features/rsyslog/outputs#destroy
       rules GET    /features/rsyslog/rules(.:format)               features/rsyslog/rules#index
             POST   /features/rsyslog/rules(.:format)               features/rsyslog/rules#create
    new_rule GET    /features/rsyslog/rules/new(.:format)           features/rsyslog/rules#new
   edit_rule GET    /features/rsyslog/rules/:id/edit(.:format)      features/rsyslog/rules#edit
        rule GET    /features/rsyslog/rules/:id(.:format)           features/rsyslog/rules#show
             PATCH  /features/rsyslog/rules/:id(.:format)           features/rsyslog/rules#update
             PUT    /features/rsyslog/rules/:id(.:format)           features/rsyslog/rules#update
             DELETE /features/rsyslog/rules/:id(.:format)           features/rsyslog/rules#destroy
```